# VB script saves a incoming message as *.msg type. Will this save the entire body as welll within that?

Tags: vba, outlook

Hi i have a VB script but I can not test it at the moment. Does anyone know if the VB script brings the body of the message automatically within the .msg file without defining it in the script?

Here is my code:

```
 Option Explicit

 Public Enum olSaveAsTypeEnum   olSaveAsTxt = 0   olSaveAsRTF = 1  
 olSaveAsMsg = 3 End Enum

 Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

 Private Const MAIL_PATH As String = "d:\mails\"

 Private Sub Application_Startup()   Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace

   Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")   Set Items =
 Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items End Sub

 Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)   If TypeOf Item Is
 Outlook.MailItem Then
     SaveMailAsFile Item, olSaveAsMsg, MAIL_PATH   End If End Sub

 Private Sub SaveMailAsFile(oMail As Outlook.MailItem, _   eType As
 olSaveAsTypeEnum, _   sPath As String _ )   Dim dtDate As Date   Dim
 sName As String   Dim sFile As String   Dim sExt As String

   Select Case eType
     Case olSaveAsTxt: sExt = ".txt"
     Case olSaveAsMsg: sExt = ".msg"
     Case olSaveAsRTF: sExt = ".rtf"
     Case Else: Exit Sub   End Select

   sName = oMail.Subject   ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "_"

   dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime   sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd",
 vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
     vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
     vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & sExt

   oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, eType End Sub

 Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _   sChr As
 String _ )   sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)   sName =
 Replace(sName, "\", sChr)   sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)   sName
 = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)   sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)   sName = Replce(sName, "<", sChr)   sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr) 
 sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr) End Sub
```

Comment: Don't know whether you've bumped into a markup problem but that code formatting is all over the place, making it near impossible to read. I doubt anyone will be able to provide a clear answer just from looking at that mess. My **guess** as to your answer will be yes as I can't see the point of saving a .msg file that DOESN'T contain the email body.

Comment: Yeah sorry someone edited it and i approved now it is hard to read. Ok thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, saving in the MSG format saves plain text, HTML and RTF body flavors inside the MSG file.